# Loading image in Android without bitmap

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap, bitmapfactory

to go straight to the point i would like to load and show a big image in my Android App, a big image like this -> http://viewhdwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Wonderful-Purple-Bridge-Wallpaper.jpg

When loading this big image its causing the OutOfMemory exception.

Doing a few calculations, if i load this image into a Bitmap that uses ARGB_8888 it would use like 285 MB of memory ( 11658 * 6112 * 4 ), and thats a lot of memory for an App. So my question is, can i load this big image into imageview without using a Bitmap? In a way that doesnt use so much memory.

Just to make an example, i opened that big Image at Windows PaintBrush and it was using like 700 MB of memory, when i opened the big image at Windows Photo Viewer it used a maximum of 30 MB (i'm using Windows 8).

Obs.: Just to clarify, making the image smaller with "inSampleSize" from BitmapFactory.Options is not an option for me, because if i reduce the image size it wont be that "big image" anymore.

**Edit 1**

I want that the user to be able to zoom into de image if he desires, so i cant lose quality (that would come with reduced image dimensions). I am aware that the Device screen itself will make a downscale of the image, but if i use a bitmap i will have the information of all the image details, but that just uses a lot of memory. Windows Photo Viewer achieve that without consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: Read carefully this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Your goal here isn't clear. Are you wanting the user to be able to zoom in and pan around the image? Otherwise why is `inSampleSize` not an option? You might want to look into [`BitmapRegionDecoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html).

Comment: "if i load this image into a Bitmap that uses ARGB_8888 it would use like 285 MB of memory ( 11658 * 6112 * 4 )" -- note that at the present time there is no Android device with a screen of that resolution or higher. For that matter, I am not aware of any mainstream display (monitor, TV, etc.) of that resolution or higher. "when i opened the big image at Windows Photo Viewer it used a maximum of 30 MB" -- Windows Photo Viewer is doing the equivalent of `inSampleSize`, then. Math does not change just because you are running Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: Chrome for Android displays that image without a problem, so one option would be to display it in a `WebView`, letting the OS solve the problem for you, however you can be sure that behind the scenes the bitmap is being sub-sampled.

Comment: @kcoppock , Just did Edit 1 for you, hope it clarifies my goal, i shall take a look at BitmapRegionDecoder